# Sequence ID is resetting to a previous value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

Sequence is getting restarted to a previous value and then causing PK issues

Below is the definition of my sample sequence object, as any one faced this issue? any problem with the cache? Please reply

**Example sequence object:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[Seq_Test] AS INT
MINVALUE 1000 
CYCLE
CACHE 500 
GO
```

Comment: What is the value of the duplicate? That is, are you perhaps hitting the max value for an inf and the sequence is cycling? But to answer your question re: caching, you might get gaps but shouldn't get duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Ben, no we are not hitting the max value.Duplicate values are not predictable.I assume issue with CYCLE alone but I am not sure how to replicate the issue, request a big help! on this

Comment: What version of SQL are you on? From a thread on the MSDN forums, it looks like there might be an issue with 11.0.3000.0 that appears to be fixed in 11.0.3128.0.

Comment: Please share the link, it would be a great help!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8909d16a-80ad-42ce-a92a-8bc80dca822d/sequence-issuing-numbers-more-than-once by way of https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790161/next-value-for-sequence-can-fail-to-return-proper-next-value

Comment: Any one else faced this issue?Pl let me know

Comment: Thank you! Ben
this will really help me